# Где ошибка в JS?

Tags: javascript

Где ошибка в скрипте ?
При воспроизведении мои переменные 100% равны , но он не работает(

```
<script>
if(1 == 1) {}
else if(2 == 2) {
var select = document.getElementById("myselect");
select.removeChild(select.getElementById("myoption"));
};
</script>
```

Comment: чему равны твои переменные?

Comment: Есть ли в консоли ошибки? Где присваиваются значения переменных?

Comment: что именно не работает? почему ты решил, что не работает?

Comment: Давайте полный js-код вместе со всеми переменными весь html-код с вот этим вот myselect. Хотя одну ошибку я уже вижу, но это потом, сперва код весь выложите

Comment: думаю что там а и б стоковые "1" и "2"

Comment: @НазарКалитюк, это не играет роли

Comment: но 1 вроде равняется "1" если нет строгого сравнения

Comment: @grundy ах, да. 2 равно.

Comment: @andreymal, ты про `;` после `if`?

Comment: @Grundy нет . .

Comment: @andreymal, а что тогда?

Comment: весь код не получится , очень громоздкий.
Переменная вот:
a = 1
b = 2

Comment: Ну во первых если a == 1 то следующее условие не выполняется

Comment: @Vipz [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: а во вторых что значит `select.getElementById("myoption")` Это легально?

Comment: @Grundy метод `getElementById` есть только у `document`, а у `select` его не будет

Comment: select.getElementById("myoption") смени на document.getElementById("myoption")

Comment: `if(1 == 1) {}` - ну всё норм. пустое тело. что еще от жизни надо?

Comment: @andreymal, Логично :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

во первых если `a = 1` то `else if` не выполняется. Во вторых метод `getElementById` есть только у `document`, а у `select` его не будет зато есть `querySelector`. А чтобы проверить 2 переменные есть `&&`.

```js
let a = 1;
let b = 2;
if (a == 1 && b == 2) {
  var select = document.getElementById("myselect");
  select.removeChild(select.querySelector("#myoption"));
}
```

```html
<select id="myselect">
<option>weqweqwe</option>
<option>yrytrtyr</option>
<option id="myoption">qweqweqq</option>
<option>adasdasd</option>
</select>
```

Comment: нужна проверка 2х условий , если a = 1 , то проверить b и если b = , выполнить скрипт

Comment: А так у вас неправильно

Comment: нужно `if( a == 1 &&  b == 2)` а не `if( a == 1){} else if (b == 2)`

Comment: Обновил ответ..

Comment: Почему не удаляется 'оption' если все верно ?

Comment: Как не удаляется? У меня все удаляется.

Comment: извиняюсь , там 4 option , а не 3.
не внимательный что то я , надо отдохнуть.
Я пробую к себе поставить , но что то не идет...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62943/discussion-between-vipz-and-duoxx).

Comment: Спасибо вам за '&&' и потраченное время.

Comment: Да время я тянул много, извините. :( Я учту и попробую быть быстрее и кратче.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так

```js
if(2 == 2 && 1 == 1) {
     var select = document.getElementById("myselect");
     select.removeChild(document.getElementById("myoption"));
    };
```

```html
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<div id="myselect">
<p>3</p>
<p id="myoption">123</p>
</div>
<p>4</p>
```

Comment: нужна проверка 2х условий. Если 1 равно 1 , начать проверку 2 на 2

Answer (score 0):

Не лишним будет объяснить логику работы вашего кода (а конкретно - работу условных операторов) с помощью псевдокода.

### Ваш код

```
<script>
if(a == 1) {}
else if(b == 2) {
    var select = document.getElementById("myselect");
    select.removeChild(select.getElementById("myoption"));
};
</script>
```

---

### Псевдокод

```
<script>
Если ( a равно 1) то {Делаем действие} // где { и } служат границами действия одного оператора
Иначе, если (b равно 2) то { // Здесь уже идёт проверка, только если в предыдущем if условие не соблюдается
    var select = document.getElementById("myselect");
    select.removeChild(select.getElementById("myoption"));
};
<script>
```

---

### Примеры работы условных операторов

```js
let a = 1;
let b = 2;
if (a == 1) {
  document.getElementById("myselect").innerHTML="Текст 1";
}
else if (b == 2) {
  document.getElementById("myselect").innerHTML="Текст 2";
}
else {
  document.getElementById("myselect").innerHTML="Текст 3";
};
```

```html
<p id="myselect">Привет Мир!</p>
```

```js
let a = 2;
let b = 2;
if (a == 1) {
  document.getElementById("myselect").innerHTML="Текст 1";
}
else if (b == 2) {
  document.getElementById("myselect").innerHTML="Текст 2";
}
else {
  document.getElementById("myselect").innerHTML="Текст 3";
};
```

```html
<p id="myselect">Привет Мир!</p>
```

```js
let a = 2;
let b = 3;
if (a == 1) {
  document.getElementById("myselect").innerHTML="Текст 1";
}
else if (b == 2) {
  document.getElementById("myselect").innerHTML="Текст 2";
}
else {
  document.getElementById("myselect").innerHTML="Текст 3";
};
```

```html
<p id="myselect">Привет Мир!</p>
```

---

### Условные операторы в операторах

```js
let a = 1;
let b = 2;
if (a == 1) { //Если a равно 1
  if (b == 1) { //Если b равно 1
      document.getElementById("myselect").innerHTML="Текст 1";
  }
  else if (b == 2) { //Иначе, если b равно 2
      document.getElementById("myselect").innerHTML="Текст 2";
  }
  else { //Иначе 
    document.getElementById("myselect").innerHTML="Текст 3";
  };
};
```

```html
<p id="myselect">Привет Мир!</p>
```

Этот вариант можно записать другим способом:

```js
let a = 1;
let b = 2;
if (a == 1 && b == 1) {
    document.getElementById("myselect").innerHTML="Текст 1";
}
else if (a == 1 && b == 2) {
    document.getElementById("myselect").innerHTML="Текст 2";
}
else if (a == 1) {
    document.getElementById("myselect").innerHTML="Текст 3";
};
```

```html
<p id="myselect">Привет Мир!</p>
```

---

### Как решается ваша проблема

Выхода два (как в примере выше):

**Можно так**

```
<script>
let a = 1;
let b = 2;
if(a == 1 && b == 2){
    var select = document.getElementById("myselect");
    select.removeChild(select.getElementById("myoption"));
};
</script>
```

**Или так**

```
<script>
let a = 1;
let b = 2;
if(a == 1){
    if(b == 2){
         var select = document.getElementById("myselect");
         select.removeChild(select.getElementById("myoption"));
    };
};
</script>
```